# Why can't I 'cd' into Bash aliases on Cygwin?

Tags: bash, windows-7, cygwin, alias, aliases

I'm using Bash via the `mintty` terminal on Cygwin, and I've created two aliases in my `.bashrc` file in my Cygwin home directory.

```
alias croot="C:/cygwin64"
alias desktop="B:/Users/User/Desktop"
```

When I enter `croot` or `desktop` into the terminal, it seems to work fine:

> B:/Users/User/Desktop: Is a directory

However, using those aliases with something like `cd croot` returns the error:

> -bash: cd: croot: No such file or directory

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alias doesn’t work the way you think it does. Do this:

```
alias croot='cd C:/cygwin64'
croot
```

Or:

```
croot=C:/cygwin64
cd "$croot"
```

Result:

```
$ pwd
/
```

Comment: So it can't be used as I was using it, in place of a path for a command? Or is it that there are certain commands it will or won't work with?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make this work. But I would not recommend it. Use [steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103391/793796) instead.

> $ help alias
>
> alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
>      Define or display aliases.
>
> Without arguments, 'alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
>      form 'alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output.
>
> Otherwise, an alias is defined for each NAME whose VALUE is given.
>      **A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
>      alias substitution when the alias is expanded.**
>
> Options:
>        -p    print all defined aliases in a reusable format
>
> Exit Status:
>      alias returns true unless a NAME is supplied for which no alias has been
>      defined.

```
$ alias croot="C:/cygwin64"
$ alias desktop="B:/Users/User/Desktop"

$ alias cd='builtin cd ' # Notice the trailing space.

$ cd croot; pwd
/
```

Note that only the word immediately next to `cd` will be considered for `alias` expansion. Hence `cd -P croot` will not work.